# Displaying a slick grid row editor in bootstrap popover

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, slickgrid, popover

I have an an edit and a delete link in a column in the slick grid. When i click on the edit button i want to a bootstrap popover with the row details in it.

I was successful to the extent that i am able to render the popover but looks like it hides behind the table. I tried setting the `z-index` but to no avail. Code below:

```
    var popoverReference = $(".growthGridActions_edit").popover({
        'title': 'Edit Record',
        'html' : true,
        'placement' : 'left',
        'template': popOverTemplate
    });
    popoverReference.click(function(e) {
        var me = $(this), rowid = me.attr('rowId');

        var editGrowthRecordView = new WTG.view.GrowthEditView({
            template:$("#GROWTH-RECORD-EDIT").html(),
            model: new WTG.Model(growthGridRef.getDataItem(rowid))
        });

        editGrowthRecordView.render();

        $("#"+me.attr('id')).attr('data-content', editGrowthRecordView.$el.html());
        var popover = $("#"+me.attr('id')).data('popover');
        popover.setContent();
        popover.$tip.addClass(popover.options.placement);
    })
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am doing something similar. I have a bootstrap modal appearing when I double-click a row in my slick grid. The modal displays the details of the row (plus some more info) which I fetch using AJAX. This works just fine, no problems with z-index.

Maybe our approaches are a bit too different but I hope the code below helps.

**The Bootstrap Modal**

```
<div id="user-details-modal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 650px">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">User View</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form class="form-horizontal" action="/user/update" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" id="userId" name="userId"/>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="firstName">First Name</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <div class="input-prepend">
                        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>
                        <input class="input-xlarge" type="text" required id="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="lastName">Last Name</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <div class="input-prepend">
                        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>
                        <input class="input-xlarge" type="text" required id="lastName" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name">
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

... more fields

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Save Changes</button>
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Slick Grid Setup**

```
setupGrid:(onDblClick)->
    grid = new Slick.Grid(@gridId, dataView, @columns, options)
    grid.setSelectionModel(new Slick.RowSelectionModel({ selectActiveRow: true }))
    grid.onDblClick.subscribe((e, args)->
        onDblClick(dataView.getItem(args.row).id);
    )
    $(window).resize(->
        grid.resizeCanvas()
    )
```

**Displaying the Modal**

```
onDblClick = (id) =>
    $userDetails = $('#user-details-modal')
    $.get('/user/' + id + '/details')
    .success((results)->
        $userDetails.find('#userId').val(results.id)
        $userDetails.find('#firstName').val(results.FirstName)
        $userDetails.find('#lastName').val(results.LastName)
        $userDetails.find('#userName').val(results.UserName)
        $userDetails.find('#email').val(results.Email)
        $userDetails.find('#password').val(results.Password)
        $userDetails.modal()
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem  as the op. Not sure why this was marked the answer since the original question was about bootstrap pop over and the answer is about a modal. I am guessing the op changed to a modal.

Anyways just posting this if anyone else has the same issue when trying to use bootstrap  popover in slickgrid To resolve that just set the container to body... data-container='body'